# Как использовать результаты groupBy в RxJava2

Tags: java, rxjava2

Есть следующий код:

```
File[] files = folder.listFiles();

Observable
          .fromArray(files)
          .groupBy(file -> getExtension(file));
```

`getExtension` - метод возвращающий расширение файла.

Как мне получить объект такого типа:

```
Observable<GroupedList> observable;
```

Код класса `GroupedList`:

```
 public interface ListOfFiles {

        class GroupedList implements ListOfFiles{

        private String extension;
        private List<File> files;

        public GroupedList(String extension, List<File> files) {
            this.extension = extension;
            this.files = files;
        }

        public String getExtension() {
            return extension;
        }

        public List<File> getFiles() {
            return files;
        }

        public void setExtension(String extension) {
            this.extension = extension;
        }

        public void setFiles(List<File> files) {
            this.files = files;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GroupedList {
    private String extension;
    private List<File> files;

    public GroupedList() {
        this.files = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}

List<GroupedList> list =
  Observable.fromArray(folder.listFiles())
            .groupBy(SomeClass::getFileExtension)
            .flatMapSingle(group -> group.collect(GroupedList::new, (groupedList, file) -> {
                groupedList.setExtension(getFileExtension(file));
                groupedList.getFiles().add(file);
            }))
            .toList()
            .blockingGet();
```

Comment: Приветствую, Сергей!
Подчеркивает GroupedList::new: Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert somePackage.GroupedList to U.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код класса `GroupedList`.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Вам нужно добавить конструктор без параметров.

Comment: Да. Все действительно помогло, спасибо.
Единственное, добавил groupedList.setFiles(list);
Т.к. в строке groupedList.getFiles().add(file); вылетала NPE